# Git: Ignore only content of the folder

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I use the following .gitignore file (global):

```
.idea
.svn
/media/covers/*
/media/tmp/*
/media/cache/*
/bin
/include
/lib
/local
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
local_settings.py
```

So in `media/covers`, `media/tmp`, `media/cache` I want to ignore all files and folders, but not this directories themselves. This .gitignore file ignore `media/covers`, `media/tmp`, `media/cache` dirs, how can I fix it?

TIA!

Comment: Git does not track directories at all, only files in the directories.

Answer (score 14):

Add a .gitignore file to the directory that you want to keep. Within that directory put

```
*
```

Now when you do a git status, you will see that the contents are not shown as being tracked, only the .gitignore file. And since the .gitignore file is in the directory, that means that the directory will be tracked, but no other contents.

Answer (score 5):

Git will not add empty directories to its index. I'm guessing that these directories are being excluded because they are empty, not because the match the ignore rules.

One way that people solve this is to create an empty file called `.gitkeep` in the directories they would like git to keep. So you could add that file to `media/covers`, `media/tmp`, etc. Then add `!*.gitkeep/` to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I like the idea of a .gitkeep file. It is self explanatory is a manner of speaking. Thanks!